# How to write T4 text template to implement interface?

Tags: interface, t4

I have a project containing several interfaces and I want to write one template to generate classes which implement these interfaces(e.g: if I have 2 interfaces, the template will generate 2 classes). Generated class is put into a specific folder.

Currently, I have two issue:
1. The my template only generate one file which contain many classes.
2. The class is created below a text template.

Below is my code:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#>
<#@ output extension=".cs"#>

<#
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"Example.dll");
Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
foreach (Type type in types)
{
    if (type.IsInterface)
    {
        string nameSpace = "Example.Client";
        string className = type.Name.TrimStart('I')";
        string interfaceName = type.Name;

#>

namespace <#= nameSpace #>
{
    public class <#= className #> : <#= interfaceName #>
    {
    }
}

<#
    }
}
#>
```

How can I generate many classes to a specific folder? Can you help me, please?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

With your template above you would just put it in the template (.tt file) in that directory.  If you want your template file to be in a higher directory look at Oleg's http://www.olegsych.com/2008/03/how-to-generate-multiple-outputs-from-single-t4-template/ Note the `SaveOutput()` method.

Comment: This is why link only answers are usually flagged on SO.  All these links are now bad because Oleg revamped his site.

Answer (score -1):

check out http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit/

also http://www.olegsych.com/2008/03/how-to-generate-multiple-outputs-from-single-t4-template/

But why bother? If it's generated code then you shouldn't need to touch it.